# How can I create a java webstart shortcut available to all users on Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows-7, java-web-start

We have a Java Webstart Application that runs under java 6 and we need to make it available to all users on a Win7 machine.

Is it possible to create the JNLP shortcut to all users during the install process?

Comment: I would recommend to use the non-Webstart version in this case. WebStart is a end-user technique AFAIK not designed to work for all users on a system.

Comment: Robert, what do you mean by "not designed to work for all users on a system"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving the JNLP file on the desktop, available to all users.  To start the app, the command line is just -> javaws  to invoke the application.

Comment: The suggestion works even in offline mode and if the application is updated on the server (updates the client automatically).